# Traefik 2.8 and regex flavor version for redirectRegex

Tags: regex, traefik

Which exact flavor & settings do I need to use on https://regex101.com/ to use the **redirectRegex** for traefik (version 2.8) middleware regex replacement ?
Is it global? greedy/not greedy? single line syntax? Do I really need to use the `^` and `$` delimiters when replacing just parts of a single url?

For simple regex, this is not much of an issue, but once you head on to a bit more complex replacements, it turns out that Regex101's *Go* language seems to not be the exact flavor that is used. Also, I can't really find the exact integration on the traefik github pages.

Reproducable example:

I want, for my default website on my domain, with lowest prio, to drop every attempt on going to a subdir while I want get/request variables in the header to remain alive.
(omitted the https tag for readability)

| original | target |
| --- | --- |
| test.example.com | `www.example.com` |
| test2.example.com/test | `www.example.com` |
| test3.example.com?foo=bar | `www.example.com?foo=bar` |
| test3.example.com?foo=bar/test4 | `www.example.com?foo=bar` |
| test.test2.example.com?foo=bar/test1/test3/ | `www.example.com?foo=bar` |

On regex101, this is easily achieved with a substitution from
`https://.*\.(example\.com)([^\/]*)(.*)` to `https://www.${1}${2}`

[Regulex](https://jex.im/regulex/#!cmd=export&flags=&re=https%3A%2F%2F.*%5C.(example%5C.com)(%5B%5E%5C%2F%5D*)(.*))
[image: Jex]

However, via traefik config (using yaml, so double escapes) the /test1 at the end of the url is not dropped.

```
middleware_redirect_test:
  redirectRegex:
    regex: "https://.*\\.(example\\.com)([^\\/]*)(.*?)"
    replacement: "https://www.${1}${2}"
```

| original | result |
| --- | --- |
| test3.example.com?foo=bar/test4 | `www.example.com?foo=bar/test4` |
| test.test2.example.com?foo=bar/test1/test3/ | `www.example.com?foo=bar/test1/test3` |

please enlighten me.

Comment: Did you try `https://.*\\.(example\\.com)([^\\/]*).*` where the last capture group is omitted and matches the rest of the line in a greedy way?

Comment: I did, @Thefourthbird. The last capturing group's brackets are indeed obsolete, so I tried with & without the last 2 brackets. But when I remove the final questionmark, I get a "too many redirects" error, which is absolutely puzzling to me. The greediness of the last group should have no effect. It doesn't on regex101, which is correct. The previous group captures everything up till the first forward slash, and I only need that group.